# BigQuery Data Transfer Service Transfer Setup (DCM)

Tags: google-bigquery, double-click-advertising

Trying to figure out how to use the transfer service for DCM data and have been running into issues. https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKiB.jpg  shows the error message I get.

I've scheduled a back fill with dates that are in my Google Bucket, yet still running into the same problem. Has anyone else had the same issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[This](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-troubleshooting) is the google documentation that I've been using to figure out what might be the issue but still coming up with nothing.

Comment: Please copy and paste your error, not use image for this.

Comment: It looks like you have scheduled regular transfer and it happens that you do not have data currently. Instead, for back filling data you should use [Schedule Backfill](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-campaign-transfer#set_up_a_backfill)

Comment: I've used the schedule back fill as well in order to pull dates in August and July. Still coming up with the same error of  "Import failed - no data was available for import. Please verify that data existence was expected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is that data in your bucket contains info for the floodlight, and not for the account.
gs://dcdt_-dcm_account3065/dcm_floodlight5199053_match_table_ad_placement_assignments_20170813_20170814_071344_596499640.csv.gz

So, in DoubleClickID you should specify 5199053

Comment: Stack Overflow customs: Remember to accept answers that give you the answer you wanted ;)